# rhel7 php71 execution issue

Tags: php, redhat, rhel7

I am attempting to get php71 running on my rhel7 system following this article https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3232341

Everything appears to install correctly

```
rpm -qa |grep php
rh-php71-php-json-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-process-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-mbstring-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-fpm-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-zip-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-common-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-xml-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-pear-1.10.4-1.el7.noarch
rh-php71-php-pdo-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-mysqlnd-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-ldap-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-runtime-1-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-cli-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-1-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-odbc-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php71-php-opcache-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
```

Running php -v on my user account returns

```
-bash: php: command not found
```

But after scl enable rh-php71 bash at root it appears to work

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2017 09:01:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend 
Technologies
```

I finally found an article that said I needed to load the php7 module in httpd.conf /w

```
<IfModule php7_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

But that still doesn't produce results. I can install php 5.4 and it works perfectly out of the box but I cannot seem to get 7.1 working for the life of me.

I've disabled selinux & the firewall incase either of those were screwing with me as well.

Comment: As root run `which php` and then check to see of the path to it is present in your regular user's `PATH` env var. I'm not directly familiar with SCL packages, but they might have additional overhead in managing which particular version of software is used on a given account, at a given time, etc.

Comment: Also configuring 1. Apache will not have any effect on the CLI. 2. Configuring Apache with SCL PHP is going to be more fun than usual. 3. Virtually none of the docs you're going to find online will cover special considerations for SCL.

Comment: wow, yeah you're not kidding that is a very involved process. I guess I'm sticking with 5.4 at this point. 7.1 isn't worth all the headache. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though I hadn't considered it required a different install process.

Comment: The sooner you upgrade to 7.x the better. 5.x is going to be entirely EOL quite soon, [[Jan 1, 2019](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)] any new development being done at this point in time should absolutely be targeting 7.x, and RHEL would be insane to not have 7.x in base EL8 which is due any time now.